# How to combine two RDDs in Spark (Scala)?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So, let's say I have the following two RDDS: 
(These are only the first few rows for each RDD)

RDD1:

```
Time                   Temp 
2014-08-12 13:20:00    22
2014-08-12 13:21:00    24
2014-08-12 13:24:00    26
2014-08-12 13:26:00    27
2014-08-12 13:28:00    22
```

RDD2:

```
Time                   Age 
2014-08-12 13:20:00    45
2014-08-12 13:21:00    45
2014-08-12 13:24:00    46
2014-08-12 13:26:00    37
2014-08-12 13:28:00    122
```

And I would like to combine them such that the column of RDD2 is added to RDD1. I can't use union since that will just add RDD2 to the bottom of  RDD1, whereas I would like to add it to the "side", if that makes sense.

Comment: You need to join them

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`join` would let you join these `RDD`s "side-by-side." From the docs:

"*When called on datasets of type (K, V) and (K, W), returns a dataset of (K, (V, W)) pairs with all pairs of elements for each key. Outer joins are supported through leftOuterJoin, rightOuterJoin, and fullOuterJoin.*"